# SELECT DISTINCT or separate normalized table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, normalization

We're making the plans now, so before I start progress I want to make sure I'm handing things in the best way.

We have a products table to which we're adding a new field called 'format', which is going to be the structure of the product (bag, box, etc). There is no set values for this, users can enter whatever they like into that field, however we want to show a drop down list of all formats that the user has already entered.

There's two ways I can think of to do that: either a basic SELECT DISTINCT on the products table to get all formats the user already filled in; or a separate table that stores the formats and is linked to by the product.

Instinctively I'd like to use SELECT DISTINCT, since it would make my life easier. However, assuming a table of a billion products, which would be the best way to go?

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` in 90% of cases means that you've made something wrong. I don't say it is useless but it is a perfect indicator of wrong query or schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to keep everything in one table, then build an index on the column.  This should speed the processing for creating the list in the user application.

I'm somewhat agnostic about which is the best approach.  Often, when designing user interfaces, you want to try out different things.  Having to make database changes impedes the creative process of building the application.

On the other hand, generally when users pick things from a drop down box in the application, these "things" are excellent examples of "entities" -- and that is what tables are intended to store.

In the end, I would say do what is most convenient while developing the application.  As you get closer to finalizing it, consider whether it would be better to store these things in a separate table.  One of the big questions is whether you want to know all formats that have every been used, even if no user currently has them defined.

Comment: Great answer, pretty much exactly what I was thinking. I figured storing the formats in a separate table would be the 'more correct' way to do it, but the benefits just didn't seem to be worth the extra work. In the end I went with the DISTINCT. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think i would opt for the second option (additional table + foreign key if you want to add constraint), just because of the volume and because you can have management that will merge similar product form for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are letting users enter whatever they want I would go with the 2nd option.

Create a new table and insert in there all the new 'formats' and link to the product table.

Be sure when you create the code to add the format the user typed in, check if there is an equal value on the database so you won't need to distinct them as well.

Also, keep it consistent, either by having only the first letter upprcase of each word.